# Loading dropdown list after modal for m is updated

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I very new to MVC and I have an issue that was real easy in webforms. I have a drop down list on a form. I have a button that loads a modal form that allows the user to add an item to the DB on the fly. I then need to update the dropdown list with the new contents of the table. I realize I need ajax to do this but I am very confused on how to initiate the update!

I have the form with the following dropdown.

```
            <div class="form-group form-group-sm required">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ListingData.Transmission, new { @class = "col-md-4 control-label" })
                <div class="col-md-8">                        
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ListingData.Transmission, (SelectList)ViewBag.TransmissionList, new { @class = "form-control"} )
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ListingData.Transmission, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    <p class="form-text"><a data-modal='' href='@Url.Action("QATransmission", "Admin", new { ListingId = Model.ListingData.ListingId}))' id=''>Quick Add Manufacturer</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I use this ajax in the main page to call the load the list code in the controller.

```
 $(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "Admin/LoadTransmissionList",
            data: JSON,
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                    $('#Transmission').append('<option value="' + value.TransmissionText + '">' + value.TransmissionText + '</option>');
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

This is my controller code for the list:

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult LoadTransmissionList()
    {

        var lstTrans = db.Transmissions.ToList();
        List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();


        foreach (Transmission p in lstTrans)
        {
            list.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = p.TransmissionText.ToString(), Text = p.TransmissionText.ToString() });
        }


        return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I have a modal form and it has a text box for entering a new list item. I need to save to the DB, which works but then! I cant come up with the reload the listbox contents part. Any help!

Thanks!

Comment: Are you saving via ajax ? If yes, in the success call back of that, you can call the action method which can get the new item/list of all items and then add the new item/re populate the dropdown.

Comment: You do not have an element with `id="Transmission"` - its `$('#ListingData_Transmission').append(...)`. And do not return a `List<SelectListItem>` - just use `var list= db.Transmissions.Select(x => x.TransmissionText); return Json(list);` and then `append('<option'>' + value + '</option>')`

Comment: Also why are you making a GET to a method marked with `[HttpPost]`

Comment: And if you modal is only adding one item, then you do not need to make you ajax call to that method, you can just append the option based on the value of the the textbox in the modal

Comment: Thanks for the hints but i must be way off.I get the id thing and changed it. But when the modal closes the new value is in the db but the dropdownlist does not contain the new value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)Make your code changes like this

```
    success: function (data) {
 $('#ListingData_Transmission').html("")
                    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                        $('#ListingData_Transmission').append('<option value="' + value.TransmissionText + '">' + value.TransmissionText + '</option>');
                    });
                }
```

hope this should work now

2) Make your form as a partial view and reload it whenever your saving something to DB.

Let me know if any issues

Comment: Thanks for the hints but i must be way off.I get the id thing and changed it. But when the modal closes the new value is in the db but the dropdownlist does not contain the new value.

Comment: You need to reload your dropdown either via reloading the page, or reloading the partial view, or ajax, in your case please try making cache: false in ajax configuration, may be its a caching problem